# Joomla 2.5 - how to access module params?

Tags: joomla, parameters, module

Does anyone know how I can get the value of the module's 'access' parameter (e.g. public, registered..etc) from within the module's helper.php? I can only see $params, which are all the module-type specific parameters, not the generic params.

I need to retrieve the access permissions and feed them to a plugin.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you will need to run an SQL query for this.

**For 1 specific module:**

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = 'SELECT access FROM #__modules WHERE element="mod_yourmodule"';
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
print_r($result);
```

Don't forget to change `mod_yourmodule` to whatever module you want the data for.

**For all modules:**

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = 'SELECT access FROM #__modules';
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
print_r($result);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Lodder, that would definitely work. Didnt think of running another query. Many thanks. Dex

Comment: Ah no, my mistake - see Elin above - from #__modules, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when you are rendering a module on a page or you want to know when it isn't being rendered?
JModuleHelper will only render a module if the user has access.

But if you want to find out for other reasons than rendering you need to query jos_modules.
Module access level actually can't be found by querying the jos_extensions table since that does not refer to specific instances of modules (e.g. main menu versus some other menu both of which are instances of mod_menu and which may have different access levels). (Use your own prefix of course.)

P.S. I think it might be worth it to put that in as a pull request so you could just get it from the helper. Seems somewhat arbitrary to me that it's not returned in the array.

Comment: Well Elin if you promise not to tell anyone, I'm writing a module to show articles, but applying ACL at only the module level, rather than at the menu/component/category/article levels. It's quicker.

Unfortunately, the Disqus comments plugin thinks I've got 'access' from the article model (which I'm not using) and needs it to make the Disqus SEF URL.

Comment: So, yes, when I'm actually rendering the module

Comment: Oh it's grabbing access from the article that's oddish because I think that's an error in the plugin because plugins don't usually get access from the access of the context they check their own (since they have their own access levels).

Comment: Anyway, I'm aware that I am flouting architecture with this, so perhaps a fresh query as Lodder suggests is the best way. Thanks Elin.

Comment: It's to help out with displaying sthg different in artilce view as opposed to blgo view:

Comment: $levels = $user->authorisedLevels();
if (in_array($row->access, $levels)) {
   if($view == 'article'){
      $itemURL = $row->readmore_link;
   } else {
      $itemURL = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($row->slug, $row->catid));
    }
   }

Comment: If you do the query you need to do it against modules. I do think it is kind of a waste that JModuleHelper isn't returning it.